# Reverse geocoding around the whole world using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I need to determine an exact country and city, having geocoordinates on hand (the whole world), I've read tons of information on the internet, but wasn't able to find a solution.

I was thinking about 3rd party services, but they seem expensive.

Is it possible to accomplish this with PostGIS?

Comment: Yes, a geographic join. But you need the data, and PostGIS doesn't help you on getting the data. Also "city' is not a well defined term on all countries.

Comment: "Is it possible?" questions are not very useful, because the Boolean answer isn't likely to be very useful (most things are possible, even if they might be suboptimal or require an inordinate amount of work).  Instead, you should focus on "How can I..." Due to the *problem-solving* nature of GIS SE, you'll likely be expected to make an attempt, and report the problem encountered.

Comment: take a look at GeoNames - https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=geonames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, PostGIS can easily work with global country- and city-level data

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it seems to me that except postgis enabled I have a whole map to be loaded in?